# How can I rotate the lineRenderer mesh to make it appear flat

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, line, plane

I'm working on a custom tool in Unity that allows me to draw roads in a similar way as City Skylines. I spawn 2 points on a plane and draw between them adding points on the endpoint to create a chain of vertices and lines drawn between each sphere.

My problem is when putting the material on the linerenderer I get the material facing the wrong direction and I cant seem to be able to rotate mesh since you can't rotate LR. Am I going about this the wrong way since I have the LR material set to my Road texture so not sure if theres a better way to do it? I attached the image of current rotation and my LR settings.I basically need the road to go from that position to flat on the plane. Ignore any other spheres. [image]

Comment: If you don't want to rotate the y of the current transform directly (which would also rotate the lineRenderer), have you considered creating an empty child gameObject of that object, and assign the lineRenderer to that one instead, so that you can then rotate its transform y?

Comment: @PhilippLenssen Ok so I tried rotating the current transform and nothing happened so Im going to try and create an empty Game object and try it that way

Comment: @PhilippLenssen still unable to rotate the mesh after attaching the LR to the child of the parent Game Objects. Not sure how to get the mesh to stick to the plane and face upwards

Comment: Strange, it worked fine here when I tried. You tried to change all values, x y and z right?

Answer (score 0):

[image: LineRenderer]

LineRenderer is facing Z axis, so to stick it on the road:

1. Rotate LineRenderer's Z axis up.
2. If you have a world position (x, y, z), you should set it as (x, z, y) in LineRenderer's positions.